# Having trouble reading back database writes

Tags: sql, vb.net, openedge, progress-db

I'm trying to confirm that I was able to write to a database. What I'm basically doing is saying

```
Insert into locationChangeTable (Col1,Col2,Col3) Values (Val1,Val2,Val3)
```

and then trying to use those values to select the record I just pushed up back down (no primary key)

```
select (Col1,Col2,Col3) from locationChangeTable 
      where (Col1=Val1) AND (Col2=Val2) AND (Col3=Val3)
```

and sometimes It finds my record and returns it, but most of the time I don't get any results from the select. I provided excerpts of my code [here](http://pastie.org/private/kravklakj0e2lq855ckg)

Does anyone know why it's not finding them like i would expect it to? or have any suggestions on other ways to confirm that my insert statement was sucessful in vb.net

Comment: Show the vb code the sends the insert and select to the db

Comment: Trying to get rep to submit synonym request :-)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I updated my pastie link to include those methods Joel.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this not satisfy your requirement rather than requery the database:

```
Dim command1 New SqlCommand("Insert into locationChangeTable (Col1,Col2,Col3) Values ('Val','Val2','Val3')", connection1)

connection1.Open()
returnValue = command1.ExecuteNonQuery()
writer.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by command1: {0}", returnValue)
connection1.Close()
```

This returns the number of rows affected by the command. Sample taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).

and for the select

```
Dim command2 New SqlCommand("Select into locationChangeTable (Col1,Col2,Col3) Values ('Val','Val2','Val3')", connection1)
connection1.Open()
returnValue = command1.ExecuteNonQuery()
connection1.Close()
```

Comment: That's ...crazy...so crazy it JUST MIGHT WORK! maybe idk. I'll have to look at it